# Predicted number of events from xtnbreg, fe make no sense

Tags: poisson-distribution, stata, panel-data, negative-binomial-distribution, count-data

I am trying to compute the number of predicted events from a fixed effects negative binomial regression model in Stata. I run the model first using random effects, then using fixed effects, and compare the predicted number of events to the actual distribution of the outcome variable, y.

Using a few different data sets, I keep finding that the predicted events make sense when I use random effects, but they make no sense in the case of a fixed effects model. **The predicted mean count is not even in the range of the original y variable.**

Here is a reproducible example:

```
set obs 1000

set seed 1
gen case = _n
expand 5
sort case
by case: gen time=_n
gen x1 = invnormal(rnormal()) 
gen xb =  0.85*x1 
gen exb = exp(xb) 
gen y = rpoisson(exb) 

xtset case time

qui xtnbreg y x1, fe
predict nu0_fe, nu0

qui xtnbreg y x1, re
predict nu0_re, nu0

sum y nu0_fe nu0_re

    Variable |       Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+--------------------------------------------------------
           y |      1700    1.198235    1.566309          0         17
      nu0_fe |      1700    50.74833    43.53816   1.449267   418.4125
      nu0_re |      1700    1.197375    1.074508   .0297296   10.54713
```

Why is this happening?